Auth.js v5 useSession(): Session data is only displayed after manually reloading the page (NextJS 14)
I'm currently building a website using NextJS 14 and Auth.js v5. My problem is the settings page. After the user logs in he is redirected to the settings page. Depending on whether the user logs in with OAuth like Github or with Credentials there should be more or less settings he can change (like 2FA...).
But for now after logging in with credentials its not updating the session automatically and I have to refresh the website to see the explicit session data. When using OAuth everything works perfectly fine. I think it has to be problem with the useSession hook from auth.js but I can't figure out how to fix this issue. I'm still relatively new to NextJS and Auth.js so forgive me if the language is a bit imprecise. I will be happy to go into more detail if something is unclear. Images and Code are below... (for full code please look on Github: https://github.com/EnXan/UTP). I used the code from this tutorial in which it works as expected: https://github.com/Hombre2014/nextjs-14-auth-v5-tutorial)

LoginPage


Settings page after log in with credentials (no session available)


Settings page after reloading


Settings page after log in with Github (no need to refresh page everything works here)



settings (page.tsx)
"use client";

import * as z from "zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useTransition, useState } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

import { Switch } from "@/components/ui/switch";
import { Select, SelectContent, SelectItem, SelectTrigger, SelectValue } from "@/components/ui/select";
import { SettingsSchema } from "@/schemas";
import { Card, CardHeader, CardContent } from "@/components/ui/card";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { settings } from "@/actions/settings";
import { Form, FormField, FormControl, FormItem, FormLabel, FormDescription, FormMessage } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { useCurrentUser } from "@/hooks/use-current-user";
import { FormError } from "@/components/form-error";
import { FormSuccess } from "@/components/form-success";
import { UserRole } from "@prisma/client";

const SettingsPage = () => {
  const user = useCurrentUser();
  const session = useSession();

  console.log(session);
  console.log("User Data:", user);
  console.log("isOAuth:", user?.isOAuth);

  const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const { update } = useSession();
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof SettingsSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(SettingsSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      password: undefined,
      newPassword: undefined,
      name: user?.name || undefined,
      email: user?.email || undefined,
      role: user?.role || undefined,
      isTwoFactorEnabled: user?.isTwoFactorEnabled || undefined,
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof SettingsSchema>) => {
    startTransition(() => {
      settings(values)
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.error) {
            setError(data.error);
          }

          if (data.success) {
            update();
            setSuccess(data.success);
          }
        })
        .catch(() => setError("Something went wrong!"));
    });
  };

  return (
    <Card className="w-[600px]">
      <CardHeader>
        <p className="text-center text-2xl font-semibold">⚙️ Settings</p>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardContent>
        <Form {...form}>
          <form className="space-y-6" onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div className="space-y-4">
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="name"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input {...field} placeholder="John Doe" disabled={isPending} />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
              {user?.isOAuth === false && (
                <>
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="email"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                          <Input {...field} placeholder="john.doe@example.com" type="email" disabled={isPending} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="password"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                          <Input {...field} placeholder="******" type="password" disabled={isPending} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="newPassword"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>New Password</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                          <Input {...field} placeholder="******" type="password" disabled={isPending} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </>
              )}
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="role"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel>Role</FormLabel>
                    <Select disabled={isPending} onValueChange={field.onChange} defaultValue={field.value}>
                      <FormControl>
                        <SelectTrigger>
                          <SelectValue placeholder="Select a role" />
                        </SelectTrigger>
                      </FormControl>
                      <SelectContent>
                        <SelectItem value={UserRole.ADMIN}>Admin</SelectItem>
                        <SelectItem value={UserRole.USER}>User</SelectItem>
                      </SelectContent>
                    </Select>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
              {user?.isOAuth === false && (
                <FormField
                  control={form.control}
                  name="isTwoFactorEnabled"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between rounded-lg border p-3 shadow-sm">
                      <div className="space-y-0.5">
                        <FormLabel>Two Factor Authentication</FormLabel>
                        <FormDescription>Enable two factor authentication for your account</FormDescription>
                      </div>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Switch disabled={isPending} checked={field.value} onCheckedChange={field.onChange} />
                      </FormControl>
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                />
              )}
            </div>
            <FormError message={error} />
            <FormSuccess message={success} />
            <Button disabled={isPending} type="submit">
              Save
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default SettingsPage;


Root-Layout (layout.tsx)
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { auth } from "@/auth";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import "./globals.css";
import React from "react";
import { Toaster } from "@/components/ui/sonner";
import Navbar from "@/components/navigation/navbar/navbar";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const session = await auth();

  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
        <body className={` ${inter.className}`}>
          <Navbar session={session} />
          <Toaster />
          <div className="pt-5">{children}</div>
        </body>
      </html>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

useCurrentUser-Hook
"use client";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

export const useCurrentUser = () => {
  const session = useSession();

  return session.data?.user;
};


I fixed the error by reloading the page after hitting the submit-button on SignIn
  const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
    setError("");
    setSuccess("");

    startTransition(() => {
      login(values)
        .then((data) => {
          window.location.reload();

          if (data?.error) {
            form.reset();
            setError(data.error);
          }

          if (data?.success) {
            form.reset();
            setSuccess(data.success);
            update();
          }

          if (data?.twoFactor) {
            setShowTwoFactor(true);
          }
        })
        .catch(() => setError("An error occurred!"));
    });
  };

